# Can I check-through luggage with Air China (domestic to international)?

Tags: luggage, pek, air-china

My flight itinerary is from Nanjing (China) to Milan (Italy) with one stop in Beijing (China). Both flights are via Air China. Can anybody tell me if my baggage will be checked all the way through?

I know it is for international to domestic flights (Milan>Beijing>Nanjing), but I'm not sure about my return flight (Nanjing>Beijing>Milan).

Comment: Thanks. The guide doesn't address this matter though.

Comment: It will be checked through, since it's on a single ticket.

Comment: In my experience, PEK segregates domestic vs. international travel. I recently did a similar journey from Shanghai and the checked luggage needed to be picked up and re-checked. The airline will have a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 5):

Air China uses terminal 3, so...

### Nanjing → Beijing → Milan

Your luggage **will** be checked all the way through. Even though you're technically leaving China from Beijing, you don't need to have your checked luggage with you to go through the departure customs procedure.
*Source*: [Beijing Airport Domestic to International](http://en.bcia.com.cn/guide/transfer_d_i.shtml), personal experience

### Milan → Beijing → Nanjing

Your luggage **will not** be checked all the way through. Since you're officially entering China in Beijing, you'll go through customs in Beijing. So you'll be picking up your luggage as an international arrival (from Milan) and then recheck your luggage as a domestic departure (to Nanjing).
*Source*: [Beijing Airport International to Domestic](http://en.bcia.com.cn/guide/transfer_i_d.shtml), personal experience